# Does weathered wood benefit from paint or sealer?

Tags: wood, painting, plywood

2-3 years ago my father-in-law created new gates for us.  He was visiting from out of town, and his visited ended before he could paint them.  At that time, I didn't understand anything about wood & thought the paint was strictly for aesthetics.  Now I know it's to protect the wood from the elements.

We live in Los Angeles, where the weather has been more gentle than other parts of the country, but we still get seasonal rain... and they've been through 2-3 seasons of it.

At this point would it make sense to paint them?

If so, I imagine I should sand them.  That's easy enough for the 2x4s, but I worry about sanding the plywood.

Picture attached.  We have small kids, who sometimes draw on them with chalk.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to be concerned about sanding plywood. The exterior layer is often quite thin, however it shouldn't be *that* thin on an exterior grade plywood. Get in touch with your FIL and ask if he remembers what kind of plywood he used. I'd guess that it's an AAX - "A" is the surface grade and means that it's got a nice, sanded finish and all voids are filled - on the right-hand gate, just above the center lock, there's a knot and an oval that doesn't match the grain - that's a filler piece in a void. The second "A" indicates that the other side is also an "A" grade finish, and the "X" is an exterior grade indicating that they used waterproof glues to laminate the plys. It may have also been pressure treated to protect the wood itself from water.

Honestly, thought, there's got to be something other than just plywood going on. Each main panel has very distinct vertical lines, and thought the grain *mostly* matches, there are changes. Is it a bead board with those thin vertical lines cut into the surface?

To prep the plywood

- Wash off the chalk - paint over the chalk will just fall off when the chalk gives up its grip, then you'll have more "permanent" drawings in those patterns. :)

  - Just some water should be sufficient to get the chalk off. You could just rub, but you might end up with splinters.
- Remove all the mounting hardware

  - It will be easier to paint if you're not trying to mask/paint around the hardware
  - Water *will* get behind the hardware and that's where it will rot out first.
- Give the whole thing a *light* sanding.

  - Your goal is to remove the surface dirt and to *lightly* smooth the surface, removing any small slivers that may have been raised by the rain, *not* to get to shiny, new looking "brown" wood instead of the grey weathered surface.
  - You'll want a finer grit of sandpaper, in the 100-150 range. This will help in removing less wood.
  - Use a sanding block so you've got a smooth surface
  - Don't sand any one area too much or you'll go through the surface layer
  - You're probably better off with too little sanding than too much, though this isn't a piece of indoor furniture, so minor flaws are probably acceptable.
- Give the solid wood a nice sanding to smooth its surface and remove any gunk

  - You can be more aggressive in sanding here if you want, but, you're planning on covering it in paint, so it doesn't need to be perfect.

At this point you should be ready to apply your finish according to the instructions on the tin. Try to get the paint into the mounting holes to cover the interior surfaces, but you don't want it sealing over the openings, though that's a fairly easy fix. Once the paint is dry, rehang the gate, enjoy, and start making plans to paint again in a few years.

Answer (score 1):

Staining it with a good quality opaque stain would provide a lot of protection. No sanding or other preparation needed. I would use oil based stain, if local regs allow it. Apply it with a cheap brush that you dispose of when finished.

If you would do this with the gates in place, be sure to place a tarp or newspapers over the nice concrete.

Comment: OP is in the South Coast Air Quality Management District, which is by far the toughest AQMD in the country.  Getting competent paints will be hard.  Can't suggest code violations here, can you take the gate to Nevada to paint it?  Or at least Bakersfield...

Comment: What about water based opaque stain?